# Is the merge operator official YAML?

Tags: ruby, syntax, yaml

I've seen some YAML files use the "merge" operator `<<`. Here's an example from the "Yaml Cookbook" on [yaml.org](http://yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#merge_key):

```
mapping:
  name: Joe
  job: Accountant
  <<:
    age: 38
```

On the other hand, I can't find any references to the merge operator in the specification docs on yaml.org.

Is this operator officially part of YAML, or is it just part of the Ruby implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47203224/210867):

> Note that merge keys are not part of the YAML specification and therefore are not guaranteed to work. They are also specified for the obsolete YAML 1.1 version and have not been updated for the current YAML 1.2 version. We intend to explicitly remove merge keys in upcoming YAML 1.3 (and possibly provide a better alternative).

However, I can personally confirm that as of today (2023-10-27), the latest version of PyYAML (v6.0.1) still supports it, as does Docker Compose when parsing a `docker-compose.yml` file.

Maybe their plans for YAML 1.3 fell through or are taking longer than anticipated, and in the meantime, everyone's enjoying the benefits of that very useful merge key too much to stop?

Answer (score 1):

http://yaml.org/type/merge.html

> Specify one or more mappings to be merged with the current one.
>
> The “<<” merge key is used to indicate that all the keys of one or more specified maps should be inserted into the current map. If the value associated with the key is a single mapping node, each of its key/value pairs is inserted into the current mapping, unless the key already exists in it. If the value associated with the merge key is a sequence, then this sequence is expected to contain mapping nodes and each of these nodes is merged in turn according to its order in the sequence. Keys in mapping nodes earlier in the sequence override keys specified in later mapping nodes.

More at http://yaml.org/type/

Comment: According to the  type page link,  it's not mandatory, but it's strongly recommended: "The use of these tags is not mandatory. However these tags represent types that are useful across a wide range of applications and it is strongly recommended they be used whenever appropriate to promote interoperability."